# Run NPX script programatically

Tags: node.js, npx

Like the title says, is there any way to call an npx script through an npm library on nodejs? Due to security concerns, the platform we are using does not allow the creation of child processes so thats why I am asking.

EDIT:
Ok, to add more context. The platform we use allows to define api calls that call a method defined in a certain language with certain libraries. For example, I can define an API call that requires a Method implemented in NodeJS. I can define the route of the api call, the method in nodejs and even the runtime. I cannot, however, call another child process from that nodejs runtime. I understand Npm can be called programatially using the NPM module from NodeJS, so I was wondering if it was possible to do the same with NPX. I specifically want to call the NPX playwright scripts that allow you to install browsers and their dependencies.

Comment: Could you please provide an reproducible example? Such as the NPX script you're trying to do, the library you're using, etc. This is not enough information where we can give anything but guesses.

Comment: all those commands lies in `node_modules/.bin/` directory, so you can invoke them directly `$ ./node_modules/.bin/<cmd>` (or `node ./node_modules/.bin/<cmd>` ?)

Comment: if child processes are not allowed then isn't that means you can't run any kind of scripts ? like no bash scripts, no makefiles and no npm run ...  scripts ? isn't thats a huge downside or I am missing something ?

Comment: Most "npx scripts" themselves are npm modules which you can install and import to your own node.js program. Take a look at the README of the module you are using which usually states all the usages.

Comment: To be honest, even the updated context doesn't provide more details. It would be helpful to know what platform your using (if it's serverless, etc. as I've had to deal with issues with process in AWS lambdas). It would also help to see what code you have thus far so we can help guide you since you talk about define API calls, etc. I would recommend rethinking the question and rewriting it with more details, any errors, any code, etc.